# Mock a method only once

Tags: rspec

Is there a way to mock a method once and only once per expectation before replacing the original mocked method?

I thought something like this would work (notice the `once`)

```
class Klass
    def self.meth
        'baz'
    end
end

describe Klass do
    subject{ described_class.meth }
    before{ allow(described_class).to receive(:meth).once.and_return('foo') }
    it{ is_expected.to eq 'foo' }
    context 'throwing in a context just to test' do
        it{ is_expected.to eq 'foo' }
        it{ is_expected.to eq 'foo' }
        it{ is_expected.to eq 'foo' }
        it 'only mocks once' do
            expect(subject).to eq 'foo'
            expect(subject).to eq 'baz' # this is the key
        end # pass
    end
end
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
   (Klass (class)).meth(no args)
       expected: 1 time with any arguments
       received: 2 times
```

I would have expected to have got that failure if I said `expect(Klass).to receive(:meth).once` rather than the more lenient `allow`.

I'm wondering how I can mock once and only once per expectation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's perhaps a bit unintuitive, but you can do this by [specifying different return values for multiple calls](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value#specify-different-return-values-for-multiple-calls) of `Klass.meth`.

In your case, you can stub the first call to `Klass.meth` with `'foo'`, and then stub every other call to `Klass.meth` with *the original implementation* of the method.  That looks like this:

`allow(described_class).to receive(:meth).and_return('foo', described_class.meth)`

The next thing we'd need to change in your test is to not use `subject` in the final test, because it is memoising the value returned when `Klass.meth` gets called the first time (which is why all the other tests that use `subject` will still pass), and hence making the second expectation in the `it 'only mocks once'` test fail.  Instead, we can just call the method directly in each spec:

```
class Klass
  def self.meth
    'baz'
  end
end

describe Klass do
  subject { described_class.meth }

  before do
    allow(described_class).to \
      receive(:meth).and_return('foo', described_class.meth)
  end

  it { is_expected.to eq 'foo' }

  context 'throwing in a context just to test' do
    it { is_expected.to eq 'foo' }
    it { is_expected.to eq 'foo' }
    it { is_expected.to eq 'foo' }

    it 'only mocks once' do
      expect(described_class.meth).to eq 'foo'
      expect(described_class.meth).to eq 'baz'
    end # pass
  end
end
```

Comment: hmm.. how about raising only once?

Comment: I feel like this won't work for a method called with various parameters